# Using this keyword within Socket.io on function

Tags: javascript, oop, node.js, socket.io, this

I'm using a socket.io listener within one of my functions to listen for a "loser" event to tell the client that the other client won. However, I can't use the "this" keyword to talk about my client while inside the socket.on function as this refers to the socket itself. Am I going about this the wrong way? Or can access the client object some other way, like super?

```
            socket.on('loser', function() {
                //Remove all current objects then restart the game.
                //THIS PART DOESN'T WORK, SINCE 'THIS' NO LONGER REFERS TO 
                //THE GAME OBJECT, BUT INSTEAD REFERENCES THE SOCKET LISTENER.
                for(var i = 0; i < this.board.objects.length; i++)
                {
                    this.board.remove(this.board.objects[i]);
                }
                //WORKS AS EXPECTED FROM HERE ON...
                Game.setBoard(1, new TitleScreen(gameType,
                        "Loser!",
                         "Press Space to Play Again", 
                     playGame));                    
            });
```

Answer (score 3):

Functions don't carry any information about the objects that reference them, you can use `.bind()` to bind the function to your object before you pass it:

```
socket.on('loser', function() {
    //Remove all current objects then restart the game.
    //THIS PART DOESN'T WORK, SINCE 'THIS' NO LONGER REFERS TO 
    //THE GAME OBJECT, BUT INSTEAD REFERENCES THE SOCKET LISTENER.
    for (var i = 0; i < this.board.objects.length; i++) {
        this.board.remove(this.board.objects[i]);
    }
    //WORKS AS EXPECTED FROM HERE ON...
    Game.setBoard(1, new TitleScreen(gameType, "Loser!", "Press Space to Play Again",
    playGame));
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: It's important to note that Function.bind isn't supported in IE 8, which is still quite prevalent for many demographics. There are some great ways to add it, though, [for example, these](https://prototype.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8886/tickets/215-optimize-bind-bindaseventlistener#ticket-215-9).

Answer (score 1):

In browser-land the common way to do this is to set a variable like `var that = this;` before you enter the function, and then use `that` instead.

However, ECMAScript5 brought in `bind()`, which allows you to prevent the value of `this` being lost. In NodeJS of course, it's safe to use this (unlike in browser-land, where you have to support older browsers).

```
socket.on('loser', (function() {
    //Remove all current objects then restart the game.
    for (var i = 0; i < this.board.objects.length; i++) {
        this.board.remove(this.board.objects[i]);
    }
    //WORKS AS EXPECTED FROM HERE ON...
    Game.setBoard(1, new TitleScreen(gameType, "Loser!", "Press Space to Play Again", playGame));
}).bind(this));​
```

For more info, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 0):

Whats wrong with something like this?

```
var self = this;
socket.on('loser', (function() {
    //Remove all current objects then restart the game.
    for (var i = 0; i < self.board.objects.length; i++) {
        self.board.remove(self.board.objects[i]);
    }
}
```